# Is there any way to get the images from a Refinery CMS account using API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms, refinery

I am using Refinery CMS for content management system. I have the images and pages-images plugin. Is there a way to access images or pagesimages of a user account using REST API?

Thanks!
Satya